# MercadoPago PHP SDK quantity error

Tags: php, api, payment-gateway

I'm using the [PHP MercadoPago SDK module](https://github.com/mercadopago/sdk-php). Here is my code:

```
$mp = new MP("CLIENT_ID", "CLIENT_SCRET");  

foreach ($_SESSION["carrito"] as $value){
    $itemCode  = $value['tagme']; 
    $itemDesc  = get_pedido($itemCode);        
    $itemQty   = $value['cant'];  // it comes from $_POST['cant']       
    $unitPrice = $value['unit_price'];

    $items[] = array(
        "title" => $itemDesc,       
        "quantity" => $itemQty,
        "currency_id" => "ARS",
        "unit_price" => $unitPrice
    ); 
}

$preference = array(
    "items" => $items,
    "payer" => array(
        'name'  => $name,
        'email' => $email
    ),
    "back_urls" => array(
        'success' => 'http://example.com/success.php',
        'pending' => 'http://example.com/pending.php'
    )
);
echo '<pre>';print_r($items); echo '</pre>';
$mp->sandbox_mode(TRUE);
$preferenceResult = $mp->create_preference($preference);
```

The `$items` outputs as below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Test Product
            [quantity] => 1
            [currency_id] => ARS
            [unit_price] => 36
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => Shipping Cost
            [quantity] => 1
            [currency_id] => ARS
            [unit_price] => 42
        )

)
```

But I got the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message '**quantity
>   must be a number**' in
>   /home/..../public_html/mercadopago-sdk/mercadopago.php:227 Stack
>   trace: #0 /home/..../public_html/mercadopago-sdk/mercadopago.php(240):
>   MPRestClient::exec('POST', '/checkout/prefe...', Array,
>   'application/jso...') #1
>   /home/..../public_html/mercadopago-sdk/mercadopago.php(126):
>   MPRestClient::post('/checkout/prefe...', Array) #2
>   /home/..../public_html/confirm.php(140): MP->create_preference(Array) #3 {main} thrown in /home/..../public_html/mercadopago-sdk/mercadopago.php on line 227

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by typecasting the quantity to INT.

```
foreach ($_SESSION["carrito"] as $value){
    $itemCode  = $value['tagme']; 
    $itemDesc  = get_pedido($itemCode);        
    $itemQty   = $value['cant'];  // it comes from $_POST['cant']       
    $unitPrice = $value['unit_price'];

    $items[] = array(
        "title" => $itemDesc,       
        "quantity" => intval($itemQty), // this solved the error        
        "currency_id" => "ARS",
        "unit_price" => $unitPrice
    ); 
}
```

My quantity seems to be string which comes from hidden and stores in session:

```
<input type="hidden" name="cant" value="1" />
```

But, MercadoPago API expects an integer in that field. So, I had to use [intval()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php).

Comment: How about if the number is decimal?

Comment: @DannyG use floatval()

Comment: There are no float quantities. It's an integer that represents how many products you have bought.

Comment: @DannyG In my case, the problem was for the `quantity` field. As @Heroselohim said, there is no float quantity. If the error occurs for the field `unit_price`, [`floatval()`](http://php.net/floatval) should be tried as @chifliiiii said.

Comment: @Sithu old, old comment, but yeah i solved the issue like that, thanks anyway :)

Comment: @DannyG I know it is an old comment :) Anyway, I'm glad to hear you solved it.